# SQL - how to get the top parent of a given value in a self referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having this small issue.

the table basically looks like the following

**Subject**

- SubjectId
- SubjectName
- ParentSubjectId

`ParentSubjectId` references the subject table itself.
and it can go down for many levels (no specific number of levels)

example (using countries just for the sake of this example):

```
  1.Europe
  2.America
  1.1 France
  1.1 Italy
  2.1 USA
  2.2 Canada
  1.1.1 Paris
  1.2.1 Rome
```

and so on..

SubjectID is Guid
ParentSubjectID is a GUID too.

Sample Overview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d36EU.png

it can even keep going down in levels indefinitely (maybe even to the street number level)

my question is:
given a subject (no matter the depth).
i would like to get the top parent of that subject (`Europe/America` in this case)

How can i do this ?
Is it possible using Basic SQL query ?

*please note that i cannot modify the database at all (i'm querying data from an already existing database)*

Comment: It should be doable using recursive Common Table Expressions I guess.

Comment: show your correct sample data. which is parent id which is subject id

Comment: Is ParentSubjectId a varchar column with data as '1.1','1.2'?? Please post sample table data..

Comment: No, they are Guids, i've added a link to a picture to my original post. it should clear i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as:

```
declare @Subject as varchar(max)
set @Subject = 'Rome'; -- set subject name here

WITH SubjectCTE AS
(
SELECT SubjectId , SubjectName , ParentSubjectId
FROM Subject
WHERE SubjectName = @Subject 
UNION ALL
SELECT C.SubjectId , C.SubjectName , C.ParentSubjectId
FROM SubjectCTE AS P
JOIN Subject AS C
ON P.ParentSubjectId = C.SubjectId
)
,SubjectCTE2 as 
(
SELECT SubjectId , SubjectName , ParentSubjectId, 
       Row_Number() over ( order by SubjectId asc) as rownum
FROM SubjectCTE
)
select SubjectName as RequiredParentName
from SubjectCTE2
where rownum =1
```

[check demo here..](http://rextester.com/ULQ26758)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to handle, just add new column HID (varchar) and fill it.

```
01     Europe
02     America
0101   France
0102   Italy
010101 Paris
```

Selecting parent:

```
DECLARE @childHID varchar(10) = '010101' --Paris

SELECT A.ID, A.Name
FROM Address A
WHERE A.HID = SUBSTRING(@childHID, 1, 2) -- first level
```

Also you can get all your branch:

```
SELECT *
FROM Address
WHERE HID LIKE '01%'
ORDER BY HID
```

Comment: i cannot do any modification on the database. i've added a link to a picture in my original post explaining how my table looks like. IDs are GUIDs aswell.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, I improved upon @Mini 's Query a bit so it stops even if the topmost parent is linked to itself and works even if a child has a smaller id from a parent:

```
declare @Subject as varchar(max)
set @Subject = 'Rome';

WITH SubjectCTE AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Subject
    WHERE SubjectName = @Subject
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.*
    FROM SubjectCTE AS P
        JOIN Subject AS C
            ON P.ParentSubjectId = C.SubjectId 
    WHERE P.ParentSubjectId != P.SubjectId 
) SELECT SubjectName FROM SubjectCTE 
WHERE ParentSubjectId = SubjectId 
    OR ParentSubjectId IS NULL
```