# How to get the root parentID of a product or menu Item

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get the root `PageID` of a child item which actually in my case is Menu item.

i have a table structure  as below
`[PageId], [PageName], [PagePath], [PageInheritance]`

What i want is a sql query that will get me the `PageID` if users select level 2  or level 3 menu item. so that i can always highlight the parent menu irrespective of its level

for example if PageID = 6 then it it should get me Root PageID as 2.

I also tried to set of SQL Fiddle for this page but it fails for some reason.

```
 CREATE TABLE PageMenu
        ([PageId] int, [PageName] varchar(5), [PagePath] varchar(50), [PageInheritance] int)
    ;

INSERT INTO PageMenu
    ([PageId], [PageName], [PagePath], [PageInheritance])
VALUES
    (1, 'Home', '/en/', 0),
    (2, 'Menu1', '/en/Menu1/', 0),
    (3, 'Child1', '/en/Menu1/Child1/', 2),
    (4, 'Child1', '/en/Menu1/Child2/', 2),
    (5, 'GrandChild1', '/en/Menu1/Child1/GrandChild1/', 4),
    (6, 'GrandChild2', '/en/Menu1/Child1/GrandChild2/', 5)
;
```

My Solution : http://rextester.com/IXEKB9577

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit challenging because you do not want "1", but "2".  So, you want the *second* level, which makes this a bit different from most such problems.  Here is one way to get the top level:

```
select pm.*, t.PageId
from PageMenu pm cross apply
     (select top 1 pm2.PageId
      from PageMenu pm2
      where pm.PageName like pm2.PageName + '%'
      order by len(pm2.PageName)
     ) t;
```

However, this returns "1", and not "2".  You can do this with simple filtering

```
select pm.*, t.PageId
from PageMenu pm cross apply
     (select top 1 pm2.PageId
      from PageMenu pm2
      where pm.PagePath like pm2.PagePath + '%' and
            pm2.PageName <> 'Home'
      order by len(pm.PageName) 
     ) t;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fdfa/5) is a SQL Fiddle

Comment: I agree with you, but i managed to make it work with the reference of example on mentioned by Ruslan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360890/sql-how-to-get-the-top-parent-of-a-given-value-in-a-self-referencing-table. I am also looking at your example

Comment: This is how i have done it http://rextester.com/IXEKB9577